# Grails 1.3.4 / Terracotta 3.5.1: Deploying a .war file fails

Tags: grails, ehcache, slf4j, terracotta

We have a Grails (1.3.4) app running with Terracotta Ehcache 3.3. We are trying to update our Terracotta installation to the latest one, 3.5.1. I added these lines in the BuildConfig.groovy:

```
inherits("global") {
    // uncomment to disable ehcache
    // excludes 'ehcache'
    runtime 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.2'
    runtime 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-terracotta:2.4.2'
    runtime "org.terracotta:terracotta-toolkit-1.2-runtime:3.1.0"
  }
```

I was able to build the .war file, but when I am trying to deploy it I am getting:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
Jun 14, 2011 1:16:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jun 14, 2011 1:16:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/cooldeals-0.3.2] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I understand that Terracotta 3.5.1 and Grails use a different version of SLF4J and there is some conflict there. What exactly should exclude, from the BuildConfig?

Thanks,
Iraklis

Answer (score 0):

Run `grails dependency-report` and check which jars have a dependency on the SFL4j Jar.

To me this jar has been a big pain in the back. For deploying on glassfish 3.1.1 I hit the same problem. I solved this by creating a war of my application and replacing the sfl4j jar in the glassfish installation with the jars from my war file.